# Extra noise when brake or drove pass speed bump

Tags: honda, noise, suspension, jazz

I have a Honda Jazz 2010 model with a 1.4cc engine. It has a semi-auto transmission gear.

Whenever I brake my car, sometimes there is rattling noise coming from the a rear tyre (nearside). Here is the noise recording: https://clyp.it/go211syd?token=a5e3fe30f812956aae83c468f1d68f0a

Also, when I drive pass a speed bump at 20mph, I hear some noise from the rear tyre (nearside). So I have to slow my car to less than 10mph if I want to avoid that noise from that rear tyre side.

1) What is the root cause of the problem? Is it due to the nearside rear tyre brake? Or Is it due to absorber at the rear side? Do I need to bring my car to garage for immediate attention?

2) If I need to bring my car to garage, how do I describe my problem to them? Is there a specific term to describe the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: I wonder, if you braking at the same time as you passing the speed bump, can you hear the rattling then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: It could be a number of things. The first place I'd look is at the shock mounts. Then every other rear suspension component and finally a full brake inspection.
2: Tell the shop exactly what you wrote in your post, except don't tell him what you think it is. Always just tell him the symptoms.